# Getter Setter Method in different java file

Tags: java, getter-setter

I have three java files(Login.java,Sales.java), and i want to pass a variable "Username" to other 3 java files so that the Sales.java can show the "Username"

This is what i done, build a loginstaff.java:

```
public class LoginStaff {
    private String Username;
    public void LoginStaff() {
    }
    public void LoginStaff(String Username) {
        this.Username = Username;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.Username;
    }
    public void setUserame(String Username) {
        this.Username = Username;
    }
}
```

In Login.java
[image]

```
...
String login = tfusername.getText();
LoginStaff loginstaff = new LoginStaff();
loginstaff.setUserame(login);
...
```

In Sales.java
[image]
    ...
    LoginStaff loginstaff = new LoginStaff();
    System.out.println(loginstaff.getUsername());
    ...

The problem is i cannot get the Username in Sales, it returned "null".
I know this is something related to new a object in different class, but i dont know how to fix this.

Comment: you are not setting the username in the `Sales` class ?

Comment: yes i would like to pass the username string from another java file, is that possible?

Comment: It seems(1) you are using different instances of `LoginStaff`, the 2nd of which is a default object with no fields set.  1)  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: It would help if you could show your `Login.java` and `Sales.java` classes in their entirety. Also, make sure you understand the distinction between a "Class" and an "Object".

Comment: @JeffreyChan, then change `private String Username` to `private static String Username`. Note that by making this field static, its value can be changed in any class by any instance of `Sales`

Comment: @Rakesh although that might solve the current problem, it's ignoring the root cause, which is a mis-use of object-orientation. Seems like there should be one instance of `LoginStaff` which is initialised in the main method and then passed to both `Login` and `Sales`.

Comment: @kikumbob, yes, I agree. Then I think applying a Singleton design pattern should solve the problem. Since this is a login application, there shouldn't be more that one instance of the `LoginStaff` class

Answer (score 6):

It's not a matter of where you're calling it - it's a matter of it being two different objects. This would demonstrate the same problem in a single method:

```
public void showProblem() {
    LoginStaff staff1 = new LoginStaff();
    // Assume typo in method name is fixed
    staff1.setUsername("foo");

    LoginStaff staff2 = new LoginStaff();
    System.out.println(staff2.getUsername()); // Prints null
}
```

Two different objects will have two distinct sets of fields - that's deliberate and a good thing. You can't create a new object and expect it to have all the field values that you set on another object.

It sounds like fundamentally the problem is that you need your `Sales` code to know about the `LoginStaff` object created in your `Login` code. Without knowing more about your design, we can't really tell you the best way of achieving that.

Answer (score 1):

If in one class you do this:

```
LoginStaff loginstaff = new LoginStaff();
loginstaff.setUserame(login);
```

And in the other class you do this:

```
LoginStaff loginstaff = new LoginStaff();
loginstaff.getUsername();
```

You are creating two different objects. Thus, for the second object, the `UserName` was never set. If you want to access the same object, you will need to reference it. A work around would be to pass a `LoginStaff` object around when the objects are initialized. This will allow you to access the same settings.

Answer (score 0):

In Sales.java

```
...
LoginStaff loginstaff = new LoginStaff();
loginstaff.getUsername();
...
```

Here 1st line creates a new object with default initialization of variables, which is **null** in case of **String** type. Before using **getUsername()**, you have to call **setUsername()**

Or otherwise create a cunstrocter in **Sales.java** which accepts the **LoginStaff** object and after setting the username at **Login.java**, pass that object to **Sales.java** and in **Sales.java** instead of creating a new **LoginStaff** object, store the object passed by **Login.java** and then use **getUsername()**

Answer (score 0):

When you create your sales object, I suggest you provide it with a MainClass(this) parameter. Obviously update your sales constructor to reflect this. This allows you to store an identical MainClass in your sales class, which you can use to query for name or whatever else you may need.

Basically Sales s1 = new Sales(this);

I have had a similar process where I had a UI bar class, but needed to start a method in the main class to act when the user clicked on a button in the UI. The way I did it was had a classwide field at the top of my main class.

so basically:

```
public class MainClass() {
private InterfaceTab interfaceTab;
//Instantiate the field in the constructor or main method of MainClass, so that way both classes can access each other: 
interfaceTab = new InterfaceTab(this);
```